# Java: pass in a string and store it

Tags: java

How would I create a method that has the input of a string and output of all the strings that were input into it like a super string?

for example in the main class:

```
a= "fido"
b= "rufus"
c= "dog"

superString(a); 
superString(b); 
superString(c); 

System.out.println(superString());  should be "fidorufusdog"
```

so far I have=

```
public static String superString (String sb) {
    StringBuilder ssb = new StringBuilder(32);
    ssb = ssb.append(sb);
    return ssb.toString();
}
```

My code below  is what I am working on for a stock simulator:

```
public class Operators {
  public static void operate(double price, double low, String company){
    double percent = (price/low-1)*100;
    double rpercent = Math.round(percent * 100.0) / 100.0; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);

    if(rpercent <= 10) {
      sb.append(company + " is trading at:");
      sb.append("the current price is:  " + price);
      sb.append("the 52 week low is:  " + low);
      sb.append("percent of 52 week low is:  " + rpercent);
    }
  }
}
```

The operate method is called in a for loop in my main method 506 times and I would like to take all 506 sb string and create a super string of all the results

Comment: Please, format you code. And make it compile with no error.

Comment: I woNder why you need it

Comment: The first example code snippet that you've given is not the same as *"a method that has the input of a string and output of all the strings"*. `superString(a)` and `superString()` would have to be two separate methods - one that takes a String and potentially returns nothing and another one that takes no input but returns a String.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding of variable scope, parameters, and returns. I'd recommend you take a few steps back and read about Java methods.

Comment: Yup I agree the pseudo code example was not that great and I will revise it and play around with it when I get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I do not underestimate the depth of the question or have your question wrong, but to me it sounds like you are asking for the static keyword?

```
class SomeClass {

    static StringBuilder accumulator = new StringBuilder();

    public String superString (String sb) {
        SomeClass.accumulator.append(sb);
        return ssb.toString();
    }

}
```

This is simple usecase of the Java static keyword. Since accumulator is declared static there will be a single instance of the variable. And this single instance will be accessed by instances of the class SomeClass. For example:

```
SomeClass a;
SomeClass b;

a.superString("aaa");
b.superString("bbb");

// now accumulator.toString() returns "aaabbb"
```

Comment: Will give that a try thanks and will this static accumulator basically save all strings from every instance of superstring in a for loop instead of erasing for previous Iteration i it like it's happening to me now?

Comment: You should read about the Java static keyword. It is an essential topic. Also see my edit. Hope it helps...

Comment: this worked along with anybody who suggested static variables. It's a temporary fix for now will look to restructure code to rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare that string builder as the static member containing class and initialize it only once

```
static StringBuilder ssb;
public static String superString (String sb) {
    if(ssb == null)
          ssb = new StringBuilder(32);
    ssb = ssb.append(sb);
    return ssb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you sir i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of probelm you've two choice :

1. Simple : create a static variable in the Java class, and manipulate it.
2. improve : create a design model which support your need.

Ex 1 :

```
public class Operators {

    private static String text ="";

    public static String superString(String sb) {        
        if (sb != null) {
             text = text.concat(sb);
        }
        return text;
    }

}
```

Ex 2 : you can use a **Collecion** or a **List** of strings.

Comment: So I'm assuming a static variable will store strings from every instance of superstring when I use it in a loop? Is it generally considered bad to declare static varibles? I know about static methods but didnot know you can declare static variables.

Comment: The static variable it's a variable of class not the instance of object. That means, it will be shared between all the instance of your object, and when it's updated all the instance will get the edited value.

Answer (score 0):

This is poor OOP design.  You would be much better off creating a class for `Stock` objects and overriding `toString` in the `Stock` class(or creating some other simple output method).  Then add each instance of `Stock` to an array and call the each object's `toString` (or other output method you defined).